# require('search') is undefined using RequireJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal, single-page-application

### #model#: **search.js**

```
define('search',function(){
    var searchCriteria = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.DeviceSerialNumber = ko.observable('');
        self.OrderNumber = ko.observable('');
        self.PosTranNumber = ko.observable('');
        self.EmailAddress = ko.observable('');
        self.SuspendedbarCode = ko.observable('');
        self.MobileNumber = ko.observable('');
    };

    return new searchCriteria();
});
```

I am trying to call the above model in **searchReturn.js** by the following code

```
define(function (require) {
    var searchObj = require('search')
});
```

When i debug the code,  searchObj is undefined. Any one can guide me to reslove?

Should i configure anything for search model?

Thanks,
Shiva Reddy

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've loaded knockout globally, but if not then it MUST be declare it before it's first used:

```
/*globals define*/
define(function(require){
    "use strict";
    var ko = require('knockout'),
    searchCriteria = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.DeviceSerialNumber = ko.observable('');
          self.OrderNumber = ko.observable('');
          self.PosTranNumber = ko.observable('');
          self.EmailAddress = ko.observable('');
          self.SuspendedbarCode = ko.observable('');
          self.MobileNumber = ko.observable('');
      };

      return new searchCriteria();
});
```

The second AMD module doesn't have a return value (probably just a copy/paste issue), but that might cause issues as well. Not sure if there's a path configured for search, but if not and the module is accessible in the same directory then it MUST be prefixed with `./`

```
/*globals define*/
define(function(require){
    "use strict";

    var searchObj = require('./search');

    return {
        searchObj : searchObj
    };

});
```

Live version avalable at: http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#so/19857807

Just to add. If the search model should be instantiated multiple times it might be better to return just the constructor function from the  search module and instantiate when needed.

#### search module

```
/*globals define*/
define(function(require){
   ...

      return searchCriteria;
});
```

#### another module:

```
define(function(require){
    "use strict";

    var searchObj = require('./search');

    return {
        searchObj : new searchObj()
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing like this,

```
    define(function(){
      var searchCriteria = function () {      
      //.....
    });
```

Comment: still it is not working by the way said.                    define(function () {
    var searchCriteria = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.DeviceSerialNumber = ko.observable('');
        self.OrderNumber = ko.observable('');
        self.PosTranNumber = ko.observable('');
        self.EmailAddress = ko.observable('');
        self.SuspendedbarCode = ko.observable('');
        self.MobileNumber = ko.observable('');
    };
});

Answer (score 0):

```
define(function (require) {
    return {
        searchCriteria: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.DeviceSerialNumber = ko.observable('');
            self.OrderNumber = ko.observable('');
            self.PosTranNumber = ko.observable('');
            self.EmailAddress = ko.observable('');
            self.SuspendedbarCode = ko.observable('');
            self.MobileNumber = ko.observable('');
        }
    };
});
```

the above code works fine for me and i am able to call my searchCriteria object.

Thanks,
shiva